# How to store class reference in enum?

Tags: java, generics

So, in my work automation tests project, I have an enum that describes project configuration parameters in AdminTool:

```
@Getter
public enum AdminParametersEnum {

    SUPPORTED_SPORTS("SupportedSports", ParamTypeEnum.JSON),
    MAPPING_SERVICE_URL("MappingService.URL", ParamTypeEnum.STRING),
    MAPPING_SERVICE_ENABLE("MappingService.enable", ParamTypeEnum.BOOLEAN);

    private final String key;
    private final ParamTypeEnum valueType;

    AdminParametersEnum(String key, ParamTypeEnum valueType) {
        this.key = key;
        this.valueType = valueType;
    }

    @Getter
    public enum ParamTypeEnum {

        JSON("JSON"),
        STRING("String"),
        NUMBER("Number"),
        BOOLEAN("Boolean");

        private String type;

        ParamTypeEnum(String type) {
            this.type = type;
        }
    }
}
```

And there is AdminService_ParametersManagement_DataProvider class, for getting values of these parameters in form of an object of some class, that describes response model of this parameter (see "getSupportedSports()" method):

```
public class AdminService_ParametersManagement_DataProvider extends AdminService_ParametersManagement_Endpoint {

    private AdminConfigurationParameter getByKey(AdminParametersEnum key) {
        return getFirstOrNull(getAll().getByFilter(parameter -> parameter.getKey().equalsIgnoreCase(key.getKey())));
    }

    private <T> T getParameter(AdminParametersEnum paramName, Class<T> paramValueToBeCastedTo) {
        AdminConfigurationParameter parameter = getByKey(paramName);

        return isNull(parameter) ?
                null :
                toObject(parameter.getValue().toString(), paramValueToBeCastedTo);
    }

    public SupportedSportsParamValueModel getSupportedSports() {
        return getParameter(SUPPORTED_SPORTS, SupportedSportsParamValueModel.class);
    }
}
```

As you can see, there is "paramValueToBeCastedTo" argument in "getParameter" method", so as a result parameter value from response is casting to needed object model in "toObject" method:

```
public static <T> T toObject(@NonNull String json, @NonNull Class<T> clazz) {
        if (json == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException("json is marked @NonNull but is null");
        } else if (clazz == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException("clazz is marked @NonNull but is null");
        } else {
            return getGson(false).fromJson(json, clazz);
        }
}
```

But in the future, there may be a lot of parameters with their own response models, and right now it's needed to create separate method for getting each parameter, like this:

```
 public SupportedSportsParamValueModel getSupportedSports() {
            return getParameter(SUPPORTED_SPORTS, SupportedSportsParamValueModel.class);
        }
```

So my question is this - is it possible to somehow store that "paramValueToBeCastedTo" class reference in "AdminParametersEnum" enum ?
Like adding one more field to this enum:

```
Class<T> paramValueToBeCastedTo;
```

And then enum value would look like this:

```
SUPPORTED_SPORTS("SupportedSports", ParamTypeEnum.JSON, SupportedSportsParamValueModel.class)
```

So as a result, I would have single method for getting any parameter

Because there is no need to pass response object model for each parameter individually

Because it's already stored in enum, like this:

```
public <T> T getParameter(AdminParametersEnum paramName) {
        AdminConfigurationParameter parameter = getByKey(paramName);

        return isNull(parameter) ?
                null :
                toObject(parameter.getValue().toString(), paramName.getParamValueToBeCastedTo());
    }
```

I tried to do it in a code, but no luck, I can't  even define this field in enum:

```
Class<T> paramValueToBeCastedTo;
```

So can you please explain if I can do it in a similar way as I described, or may be in some other way by using different approach ?

I just need to somehow store that response model class reference for each admin parameter ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you should realise that with a signature like this:

```
private <T> T getParameter(AdminParametersEnum paramName)
```

The only way to infer the type parameter `T` is from the return type. The enum parameter cannot contribute to type inference at all. You can't say anything like "`T` must be the same type as the `Class` associated with the `paramName` parameter". This means that the caller is allowed (at compile time) to do this:

```
// This will throw an exception at runtime
Integer definitelyTheWrongType = getParameter(AdminParametersEnum. MAPPING_SERVICE_ENABLE);
```

Now with that disclaimer done, the way to add the field to the enum is to use a `Class<?>`:

```
private Class<?> paramValueToBeCastedTo;
```

Change the enum constants and constructors, and add a getter for it. Then you can rewrite `getParameters` as:

```
private <T> T getParameter(AdminParametersEnum paramName) {
    AdminConfigurationParameter parameter = getByKey(paramName);

    return isNull(parameter) ?
            null :
            toObject(parameter.getValue().toString(), 
            (Class<T>)paramName.getParamValueToBeCastedTo());
}
```

Notice the unchecked cast to `Class<T>`. This is due to the inherent unsafe-ness of this method, as I mentioned at the start.